# Split string in alphabet and number

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Would anyone be able to assist me with some regex.
I want to split the following string into alphabet and number.

Example 
String `ns01sp0001` after split it should be

`ns01sp`  and `0001`.

I tried with below regex.

```
String array[] = str.split("[^A-Z0-9]+|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])");
```

For upper case it's return

```
[NS, 01, SP, 0001]
```

but for lower case it's return

```
[, 01, 0001] // not able to get alphabet.
```

is there any way to get output like

```
[NS01SP,0001] // if input = NS01SP0001
[ns01sp,0001] //if input = ns01sp0001.
```

Comment: Will there always be two elements? If not, by what rule does `01` become part of `ns01sp` and not its own element?

Comment: has your string a fixed lenght? or are eyerytime 4 numbers at the end?

Comment: it might be dynamic as per question analysis

Comment: add `(?i)` for both upper and lower case. `String array[] = str.split("(?i)[^A-Z0-9]+|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])");`

Comment: @Zorian not fixed length.It can be any length. General Format <alpha-numeric part><numeric part>.

Comment: @SnehalPatel try to provide a clear cut explanation at very first.

Comment: ok, I don't write an own answer take the one from anubhava (it has a link that directs to a test-demo^^)

Comment: @SnehalPatel Why use `split()` at all? Why not just something like `/^(\w+?)(\d+)$/`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
String tok[] = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d+\\b)");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH6yT0/2)